Live Server in VSCode Not Refreshing Browser Despite Autosave Enabled
I am facing an issue with the Live Server extension in Visual Studio Code. Even though I have enabled Autosave and set it to 100ms, the browser does not refresh automatically when I make changes to my files.
Here are the details of my setup:

VSCode Version: 1.96.0
Live Server Extension Version: 5.7.9
OS: macOS Sequoia
Steps Taken to Resolve:

Checked that Autosave is enabled and works (files save automatically).
Ensured that Live Server is running and the browser opens correctly.
Verified that the file I am editing is in the workspace served by Live Server.
Tried restarting VSCode and Live Server multiple times.



I expected the browser to refresh automatically whenever I save changes, but this doesn't happen. I have to refresh the browser manually to see the updates.
I have also reviewed the Live Server settings but couldn't identify anything unusual.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows how to resolve this? Any help would be appreciated.
